# Как решить конфликт jQuery и MooTools на VirtueMart?

Tags: jquery, virtuemart, joomla, mootools

Здравствуйте, форумчане!
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему..
Все что не касается `VirtueMart`, работает отлично.
Что касается `VirtueMart`, частично не работает (например в корзине условия обслуживания, продолжить покупки, в товаре задать вопрос по этому товару и т.д.). 
Сам `VirtueMart` работает на сколько я знаю на библиотеке `MooTools`.
На сколько я понял, это идет конфликт библиотек.
Как разобраться и решить ситуацию я не знаю. Помогите, пожалуйста!
Сайт http://kaychyk-s.ru. 
Joomla!, 2.5.9.
VirtueMart 2.0.18

Answer (score 3):

Я нашел аж 4 включения различных jQuery.js в `<head>-области`. Оставьте только первый скрипт и всё нормально заработает.

[image]

Comment: во это солянка)))

Comment: Вообще АД. Почему люди до сих пор пользуются Джумлой??

Comment: это жумла! там почти всегда так, они цепляются за moo tools, а тем кто жумлу юзает проще jquery, потому такой винигрет постоянно.

Comment: @eicto, может стоит задуматься о качестве ПО? Вы носите обувь на два размера меньше? А зачем вы пользуетесь джумлой?

Comment: я жумлой не пользуюсь, я иногда ее поддерживаю. на сегодня у меня codeigniter актуально (yii что-то не вдохновил)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Disable the $ global alias completely
jQuery.noConflict();

// For jQuery scripts
(function($){

// set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias to jQuery
... here is your jQuery specific code ...

})(jQuery);

// For Mootols scripts
(function($){

// set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias 
// to Mootools document.id
... here is your Mootools specific code ...

})(document.id);
```

ну и углубиться в чтение [noConflict документации](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

---

еще примеры уже с сайта joomla:

```
сразу после объявления библиотек пишем:    

<script type="text/javascript">    
    jQuery.noConflict();    
</script>

В самом скрипте знаки долара $
заменяем на jQuery. То есть если у нас
была такая функция:

$(document).ready(function()  {
    $("#idv p.testclass").click(function()
    { /* .... */ }
}

после замены будет выглядить:

jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function()  {
    jQuery("#idv p.testclass").click(function()
    { /* .... */ }
}
```

пользуйте гугл. там все есть...

Comment: отностся не только к виртуамаркет, а вообще использование jquery и mooTools вместе. так же это не панацея от всех несовместимостей :)

Comment: Если не трудно, подскажите куда именно этот код мне нужно вставить?